# Form with JQuery Steps using aui:form tag in Liferay submits no data

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, liferay, jquery-steps

I built a portlet and added a entity named Idea. There are two JSPs, one is the view and one the edit.
In the view there is only a button to create a new Idea and a table showing all ideas. Clicking on the button shows the edit jsp.

There is a form with two fieldsets and input stuff.
The "problem" is i cannot use the `<aui:form ...` stuff because it won't work with JQuery steps (or better, i cannot get it working). So i am using normal  tag and also JQuery steps is providing the submit button which is only a `<a href="#finish" ...>`. So that wont bring the form to submit and the data being in the database.
So I tried to do it within the javascript code of the definition of jquery steps like here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $("#wizard").show();

form.steps(
   {
       headerTag : "h3",
       bodyTag : "fieldset",
       transitionEffect : "slideLeft",
       onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {

            alert("Submitted!");
            var data = jQuery("#wizard").serialize();
            alert(data);
            jQuery("#wizard").submit();
            form.submit();[/b]
          },
       onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
           //I tried also here..
       },

    });
});
```

But even if i declare the data explicitely it wont put it in the db.
So my idea was that the "controller" class which calls the "addIdea" function is never called.
How am I solving the problem?

Here is also my jsp code for the form part:

```
<aui:form id="wizard" class="wizard" action="<%= editIdeaURL %>" method="POST" name="fm">
     <h3>Idea</h3>
     <aui:fieldset>
        <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirect %>" />

        <aui:input name="ideaId" type="hidden" value='<%= idea == null ? "" : idea.getIdeaId() %>'/>

        <aui:input name="ideaName" />
     </aui:fieldset>
     <h3>Idea desc</h3>
     <aui:fieldset>
         <aui:input name="ideaDescription" />

     </aui:fieldset>

     <aui:button-row>
         <aui:button type="submit" />

         <aui:button onClick="<%= viewIdeaURL %>"  type="cancel" />
     </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

Is there a way to "teach" JQuery Steps the `<aui:***` tags? I tried it already while initializing the form but it won't work. To get it working using the aui tags would be great. Because otherwise the Liferay portal wont get the data or it would get it only with hacks right?

€dit: What I forgot, when I submit the form using javascript submit, it creates a new dataentry in the db but no actual data in it.

€dit2:

The editIdeaURL is referenced a bit over the form here:

```
<portlet:actionURL name='<%=idea == null ? "addIdea" : "updateIdea"%>'
    var="editIdeaURL" windowState="normal" />
```

and the addIdea code looks as follows:

In the IdeaCreation class first this:

```
public void addIdea(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    _updateIdea(request);

    sendRedirect(request, response);
}
```

Where `_updateIdea()` is:

```
private Idea _updateIdea(ActionRequest request)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {

    long ideaId = (ParamUtil.getLong(request, "ideaId"));
    String ideaName = (ParamUtil.getString(request, "ideaName"));
    String ideaDescription = (ParamUtil.getString(request, "ideaDescription"));

    ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
            Idea.class.getName(), request);

    Idea idea = null;

    if (ideaId <= 0) {
        idea = IdeaLocalServiceUtil.addIdea(
                serviceContext.getUserId(),
                serviceContext.getScopeGroupId(), ideaName, ideaDescription,
                serviceContext);            
    } else {
        idea = IdeaLocalServiceUtil.getIdea(ideaId);

        idea = IdeaLocalServiceUtil.updateIdea(
                serviceContext.getUserId(), ideaId, ideaName, ideaDescription,
                serviceContext);
    }

    return idea;
}
```

And to finally put the data using `IdeaLocalServiceImpl`:

```
public Idea addIdea(
        long userId, long groupId, String ideaName, String ideaDescription,
        ServiceContext serviceContext)
throws PortalException, SystemException {

    User user = userPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(userId);

    Date now = new Date();

    long ideaId =
        counterLocalService.increment(Idea.class.getName());

    Idea idea = ideaPersistence.create(ideaId);

    idea.setIdeaName(ideaName);
    idea.setIdeaDescription(ideaDescription);

    idea.setGroupId(groupId);
    idea.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
    idea.setUserId(user.getUserId());
    idea.setCreateDate(serviceContext.getCreateDate(now));
    idea.setModifiedDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate(now));

    super.addIdea(idea);

    return idea;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you please show me the code for editIdeaURL?

Comment: I added all relevant code for adding an idea. 
While doing that I had an idea. This code is only called while using the `<aui:form>` tags right? So it cannot work at all when I will use only the form tag right? So it should be with the `<aui:form>` tag but then I won't be able bring the JQuery Steps to work.

Comment: Hi! No, it's way simpler than what you think: the `aui:form` just renders an HTML `form` with some CSS classes and some Javascript code around, but it's still an HTML form. You want to execute an action on your portlet, that is the browser has to make a POST request to the server with an Action URL. The action attribute on the `aui:form` will be the action attribute of the HTML `form` tag, so you should be able to call the portlet action by submitting that form. Try to analyze the source of the page and see if it matches. And what happens when you submit the form? Errors on the Liferay log?

Comment: You need to use <portlet:namespace/> in jQuery when you are referring aui form. i.e jQuery("<portlet:namespace/>#wizard")

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreaDiGiorgi , that gave me a better understanding of what is happening :)
But the solution to that was partly the one of @LuckyBoy . Thank you. I don't want to do all that namespace stuff in the javascript part, so I tried to insert it into the form itself in front of the input name attributes and magically it worked :)

As you can see here:

`<input id="<portlet:namespace/>ideaName"
    name="<portlet:namespace/>ideaName" type="text" class="required">`

For me that looks kind of weird but it works and it "feels" better than having it in the js part.

Comment: Shall I create an detailed answer for that to explain it?